# Local files open slowly in a browser

Tags: windows, windows-7, firefox, browser

Sometimes, if I open a *local* file in the browser (e.g. `file:///C:/Documentation/index.html`), my browser (Firefox) shows the message

> Searching unpkg.com

in the lower left corner, which takes some seconds (or even more if I'm not connected to the Internet), and only *then* it displays my local document. *No error messages, only delay.*

The same behavior, if I (then) click a link to other local document. Very irritating.

Why, and how to prevent such a behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because somewhere in the index.html document, there is content that points to npkg.com. Firefox will do a DNS lookup for this domainname and once it got the ip address for this domain it can connect to the server to download the content that is associated, such as an image, etc.

If you go offline, it will still try to connect to the server over internet, but it cannot, so a time-out is reached, and thus the loading of the page is even slower.

In order to prevent it, edit the index.html, find any external resources you don't need, and edit them out.

Just because your index.html file is a local file doesn't mean it cannot contain content that exists over the internet.

If you need to keep all images etc in tact, you can consider to open the index.html, let it load once, then save as web archive (Single file html .mhtml). It will download all files and embed it inside the file before saving. Any link to external site will still connect to that page over the internet though.